# org.eclipse.core dependency to org.eclipse.runtime suddenly changed

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2, osgi, osgi-bundle

We compile an Adobe CQ project (services, taglib, view, content, etc.) with maven. At some point in time, we introduced the following dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>resources</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0-v20070604</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.equinox</groupId>
            <artifactId>registry</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0-v20070522</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jobs</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0-v20070423</version>
        </dependency>
```

This resulted in the following dependencies e.g. for org.eclipse.resources (extracted with mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose ):

```
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.core:resources:jar:3.3.0-v20070604:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.core:expressions:jar:3.3.0-v20070606-0010:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.eclipse.core:runtime:jar:3.3.100-v20070530:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.core:filesystem:jar:1.1.0-v20070606:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.eclipse.equinox:common:jar:3.3.0-v20070426:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.eclipse.equinox:registry:jar:3.3.0-v20070522:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.eclipse:osgi:jar:3.3.0-v20070530:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.core:runtime:jar:3.3.100-v20070530:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.eclipse:osgi:jar:3.8.2.v20130124-134944:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.eclipse.equinox:common:jar:3.3.0-v20070426:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.eclipse.core:jobs:jar:3.3.0-v20070423:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.eclipse.equinox:registry:jar:3.3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:jar:3.2.100-v20070522:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.eclipse.equinox:common:jar:3.3.0-v20070426:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.core:contenttype:jar:3.2.100-v20070319:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- (org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:jar:3.2.100-v20070522:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  +- (org.eclipse.equinox:registry:jar:3.3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.eclipse.equinox:common:jar:3.3.0-v20070426:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.equinox:app:jar:1.0.0-v20070606:compile
[INFO] |        +- (org.eclipse.equinox:registry:jar:3.3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        \- (org.eclipse.equinox:common:jar:3.3.0-v20070426:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

Then, from Monday 19th of August 2013 to the 20th of August, the org.eclipse:osgi dependency suddenly changed from 3.3.0-something to 3.8.2-something without any apparent reason (This broke our build quite nastily):

```
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.core:resources:jar:3.3.0-v20070604:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.core:expressions:jar:3.3.0-v20070606-0010:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.eclipse.core:runtime:jar:3.3.100-v20070530:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.core:filesystem:jar:1.1.0-v20070606:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.eclipse.equinox:common:jar:3.3.0-v20070426:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.eclipse.equinox:registry:jar:3.3.0-v20070522:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse:osgi:jar:3.8.2.v20130124-134944:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.core:runtime:jar:3.3.100-v20070530:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.eclipse:osgi:jar:3.8.2.v20130124-134944:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.eclipse.equinox:common:jar:3.3.0-v20070426:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.eclipse.core:jobs:jar:3.3.0-v20070423:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.eclipse.equinox:registry:jar:3.3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:jar:3.2.100-v20070522:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.eclipse.equinox:common:jar:3.3.0-v20070426:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.core:contenttype:jar:3.2.100-v20070319:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- (org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:jar:3.2.100-v20070522:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  +- (org.eclipse.equinox:registry:jar:3.3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.eclipse.equinox:common:jar:3.3.0-v20070426:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.equinox:app:jar:1.0.0-v20070606:compile
[INFO] |        +- (org.eclipse.equinox:registry:jar:3.3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        \- (org.eclipse.equinox:common:jar:3.3.0-v20070426:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

We were able to resolve this by adding the dependency explicitely:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
        <artifactId>osgi</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0-v20070530</version>
    </dependency>
```

But still, we do not have any clue, why the dependency changed. Does anybody know the reason or experienced the same issue?

Comment: What repository are you using?

Comment: We were using the Atlassian repository https://repository.atlassian.com/maven2/ , but changed that AFTER the dependency change to 
https://maven.atlassian.com/content/groups/public/ Because we noticed, that the first repository is ot available anymore.

Comment: Are you using version ranges?

Comment: No, definitely not for the org.eclipse packages (see above code snippet from pom.xml).

Comment: Ignore comment above, I just found out that a change in maven-metadata.xml for org.eclipse.osgi occured in http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public on 20th of August. This seems to have caused the dependency change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through pom files, .m2/repository/repository.xml and several maven-metadata.xml files, I found the root cause.

The [maven-metadata.xml file in Maven repository http://repo.adobe.com for org.eclipse.osgi](http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/eclipse/osgi/maven-metadata.xml) seems to have been changed on 20th August. For some reason the date of this file was reset now to 11th of July, but the change remains:

The metadata file changed from

```
<metadata>
<groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
<artifactId>osgi</artifactId>
<version>3.3.0-v20070530</version>
<versioning>
<versions>
...
</versions>
<lastUpdated>20071127073207</lastUpdated>
</versioning>
</metadata>
```

to

```
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
<groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
<artifactId>osgi</artifactId>
<version>3.3.0-v20070530</version>
<versioning>
<latest>3.8.2.v20130124-134944</latest>
<release>3.8.2.v20130124-134944</release>
<versions>
...
</versions>
<lastUpdated>20130711152942</lastUpdated>
</versioning>
</metadata>
```

Obviously, the latest version was provided after the change, which is now 3.8.2 and not 3.3.0 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely caused by version ranges. These ranges do not even have to be used for the Eclipse artifacts.

Assume you depend on [1,2) and 1.1, and 1.2 are available. At a moment in time, 1.3 is added that has different dependencies. If it finds multiple groupId:artifactId with a different version then it picks the first it finds. Maven follows a breadth first strategy to find dependencies so that you can override it in your top level pom. This is of course very obscure and error prone. A better way is to specify all your app dependencies in one pom so you can ensure valid versions.